# IF AND/OR Construction not working

Tags: c#, regex

Please see the code below, in the last IF statement, I've tried different combinations of either "&&" or "||" but can only get a valid input in this example if both format booleans are set to true. Any other way I've tried writing the IF statement, either validation always returns error, or the validation rules stop applying.

```
private static readonly Regex regexSSNDashes = new Regex(@"^\d{3}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{4}$");
private static readonly Regex regexSSNNoDashes = new Regex(@"^\d{3}\d{2}\d{4}$");

public static string SSN(String propertyName, bool isRequired, bool allowDashFormat, bool allowNoDashFormat)
    {
        if ((String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName)) 
            && (isRequired == true))
        {
            return "SSN required.";
        }

        if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            && ((!regex.SSNDashes.IsMatch(propertyName)) && (allowDashFormat == true))
            && ((!regex.SSNNoDashes.IsMatch(propertyName)) && (allowNoDashFormat == true)))            
        {
            return "Invalid SSN.";
        }   

        return null;      
    }
```

Based on the answers and feedback below, here's the completed code which works wonderfully and is easily expandable by writing more Regex statements (I'll probably add EIN in the future) or write different strings to check for different phone formats are acceptable credit cards, etc.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class ValidationRules
{
    // SSN Rules
    // Format 123-45-6789
    private static readonly Regex regexSSNDashes = new Regex(@"^\d{3}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{4}$");
    // Format 123456789
    private static readonly Regex regexSSNNoDashes = new Regex(@"^\d{3}\d{2}\d{4}$");

    /// <summary>
    /// Get error string if property is not in the specified formats.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The property being validated.</param>
    /// <param name="isRequired">Bool value if the property is required to be filled else may be null</param>
    /// <param name="allowDashFormat">Bool value if format 123-45-6789 is allowed.</param>
    /// <param name="allowNoDashFormat">Bool value if format 123456789 is allowed.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns custom string for error type specified if error exists, else returns null.</returns>
    public static string SSN(String propertyName, bool isRequired,
        bool allowDashFormat, bool allowNoDashFormat)
    {
        if (isRequired && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
        {
            return "SSN required.";
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName) &&
            !(allowDashFormat && regexSSNDashes.IsMatch(propertyName)) &&
            !(allowNoDashFormat && regexSSNNoDashes.IsMatch(propertyName)))
        {
            return "Invalid SSN.";
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your logic again.  Step through with the debugger.  I think you will see your problem

Comment: Probably not your issue, but just like in math, you don't need extra parentheses. They just muddle things up. For example, `3 * (5 + 6)` is equal to 33, and so is `3 * ((5 + 6))`. But one is cleaner to read. This matter much more in C# than in math, where parentheses are also used for method calls, so you want to remove those unneeded parentheses when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is off.  It should be this:

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName) && isRequired)
{
    return "SSN required.";
}
else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName) &&
    !(allowDashFormat && regex.SSNDashes.IsMatch(propertyName)) &&
    !(allowNoDashFormat && regex.SSNNoDashes.IsMatch(propertyName))         
{
    return "Invalid SSN.";
}
```

In plain English, this says that if the SSN is not null or empty *and* the input fails both regex patterns, depending on the dash mode, then the SSN is considered invalid.

The heart of the expression I wrote above is something called De Morgan's Law.  It says that `NOT(p OR q) == NOT p AND NOT q`.

**Edit:**

I would propose actually using a single regex pattern to cover both versions of acceptable social security numbers:

```
Regex bothSSNRegex = new Regex(@"^(?:\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4})|(?:\d{7})$");
```

Comment: Works perfect, thank you. I didn't think to put the not "!" outside the parentheses and didn't know you could check a bool without an "==".

Comment: The `String.IsNullOrEmpty` is a duplicate check and should be omitted completely, it was already checked at the top and therefore cannot be true at this point.

Comment: @RonBeyer You're right, I missed that, and I think it should follow if-else in this case.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you should also check the bool before doing the Regex processing

Comment: I only used the else if part and still have 2 separate null checks because the first is also checking if it's actually a required field, if not, nulls are okay but a textbox full of spaces isn't which regex checks the spaces.

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted answer is technically correct, let's ask which one is more maintainable, this one:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName) &&
    !(regex.SSNDashes.IsMatch(propertyName) && allowDashFormat) &&
    !(regex.SSNNoDashes.IsMatch(propertyName) && allowNoDashFormat))         
{
    return "Invalid SSN.";
}
```

or this one:

```
//You've already checked for a null string, it doesn't need to be repeated here
if (allowDashFormat)
{
    if (!regex.SSNDashes.IsMatch(propertyName))
        return "Invalid SSN";
}
else
{
    if (!regex.SSNNoDashes.IsMatch(propertyName))
        return "Invalid SSN";
}
```

The point is not to make things complicated for the sake of making them short. The compiler will take care of that for you. Write maintainable/readable code, not short code.

Comment: Actually I don't think this is the better answer either.  The best answer would probably use a single regex pattern to cover both types of acceptable social security numbers.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't think that fits how the OP is writing it though, seems there is an option to turn on/off the dashed format, so you'd still have to change the regex depending on if dashes are allowed or not. A single regex would match both regardless of the `allowDashFormat` flag.

Comment: I agree nested if statements are easier to read, but the allow bools are to try to make the code reuseable so depending on the app requester's requirements I can specify only allow "123-45-6789," "123456789," or if they want, both can be valid formats at the same time.

Comment: @SgtLundy A simple/readable modification to the above, but lets say you wanted to add EIN's to your original code, how would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. you should be good.

checking Boolean condition `allowDashFormat` before checking `regExMatch` improves the performance. as there is no need to check for regExMath if allowDashFormat is false.

```
public static string SSN(String propertyName, bool isRequired, bool allowDashFormat, bool allowNoDashFormat)

    {

 if ((String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
            && (isRequired == true))
        {
            return "SSN required.";
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName)
            && (allowDashFormat && !regex.SSNDashes.IsMatch(propertyName)
            && (allowNoDashFormat && !regex.SSNNoDashes.IsMatch(propertyName))))
        {
            return "Invalid SSN.";
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: I think some explanation would make your answer _much_ better.  It also might be worth mentioning why you switched the order up (check the bool before the regex)

Comment: The goal is a reusable rule I can copy into any app so the requester in the requirements can specify "I only want format: 123-45-6789, 12345678, or both." and then I can just take 2 seconds to bit flip as needed.

Comment: ok. if that is case checking allowDashformat ahead is better option.